# javascript detect scrolling past the end of the window when scroll event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

I have a site in which all sections take 100vh/vw, and I want to animate the opacity transition when user attempts to scroll up/down.

The thing is, the scroll event doesn't fire because the window hasn't really scrolled.

here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/goldylucks/pen/YzaNyNK), and the gist of it:

```
// css
.section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.section.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

// html
<div className="section active">Some stuff here...</div>
<div className="section">Some stuff here...</div>

// js
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  console.log("never fires")
})
```

is this even possible?

And if not, any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change keyword scroll to wheel,
this event fires when you try to scroll from mouse/pad(using fingers)even there is not scroll

```
window.addEventListener("wheel", () => {
  console.log("event fires")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the `wheel` event and then if the user scrolls down, you can set the `opacity` of the next section to 1 and vice versa.

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
  let element = document.querySelector('.active');
  element.style.setProperty('opacity', 0);
  if ( e.deltaY > 0 ) {
    element.nextSibling.style.setProperty('opacity', 1);
  }
  else {
    element.previousSibling.style.setProperty('opacity', 1);  
  }
});
```